# NoSuchFileException/FileNotFounException. Is there universal way to know path(or paths) where this file was looking for?

Tags: java, io, filenotfoundexception, nosuchfileexception

often I have `NoSuchFileException` and `FileNotFounException` problem. And every time I should to google, read documenatation where concrete method searches this file or folder. I don't understand why don't I see error message in format -I tried to search your file in following paths .... but it doesn't exist there.

Maybe does exist way to get message in following format?

Comment: That completely depends on what threw the exception.

Comment: last time it was java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException

Comment: It completely depends on the _code that threw the exception_.

Comment: I am about classes from rt.jar